# how to handle dollar sign in safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

I have this html label `<label style="font-size: 20px;">$</label>` a dollar sign ($) is inside it. It works fine with chrome but when using safari it just acts weird and it messes with my javascript. Is their another way to output/print a dollar sign in html for safari?

My code is basically [this](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#basic-form). So when adding the label with the dollar sign ($) the steps "disappear" and I get a flat html.

Comment: We need far more information. Can you show a [mcve] using the `[<>]` snippet editor? We want to see the script that fails and the context of the label

Comment: Do you have any Currency Converter Installed in Safari?

Comment: @thezeeshantariq I don't. I even tried on a different Mac

Comment: @mplungjan I added a link where I got my code from and it's basically that.